# How to extract only the numbers of a file in C?

Tags: c

I am learning C but I have a problem with an exercise, I have a file and I want to save only the numbers within an array but I do not know how to ignore the column with the word rowX.

Example of the file.

```
row1 1 2 4 6
row1 3 2 3 7
row1 4 3 7 6 2
row2 2 3 5 6 4
row2 1 1 8
row2 5 3 4 4 4
row3 1 4 3 2 3 5
row3 6 1 7 
row3 7 1 9
```

The dimensions of the array correspond to the number of rows of numbers in total and the columns of the longest row but I do not know how to extract that information.

In other exercises where they only have numbers in the file I used this code, but I do not know how to modify it for this case.

```
FILE *f;
f = fopen("example.txt","r");
if (f == NULL)
{                           
  printf("\nERROR\n");  
    return -1;
}
int matrix[row][col];
while(1)
{                                      
  if (feof(f))
      break;
    for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < col; ++j)
      {
        fscanf(f,"%d\n", &matrix[i][j]);
      }
    }
}
```

For the example I thought about adding 0 to the blanks to get the following matrix:

```
1 2 4 6 0 0
3 2 3 7 0 0
4 3 7 6 2 0
2 3 5 6 4 0
1 1 8 0 0 0
5 3 4 4 4 0
1 4 3 2 3 5
6 1 7 0 0 0
7 1 9 0 0 0
```

but I do not know how to implement it, I hope you guys can help me or advise me on how to do this problem

Comment: They question is unclear. Where do `row` and `col` vars come from? Do the lines in the file that start with the same name go in the same row? Should row 1 of the array be `1 2 4 6 3 2 3 7 4 3 7 6 2`?

Comment: row and col are variables that I defined previously and you are right the row 1 must be 1246323743762, but I don't know how to explain that and only ask for obtain the numbers and work with that to obtain the real matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example should work as if you are able to preinitialize the matrix, otherwise you will need to modify it.

What you could do:

1) Read the file into a buffer, you can parse out the row* portion of the file.

2) Find the largest row in the buffer(The one with most numbers, and find the number of rows

3) Initialize the matrix

4) Parse the buffer into the matrix

```
int c;
int seen = 0;
int column = 0;
int row = 0;
while ((c = getc(f)) != EOF){
  if(seen == 0 && c ==  ' '){
   seen = 1;
  } else if(seen == 1 && c != ' '){
   matrix[row][column] = c;
   column = column + 1;
  } else if(c == '\n' || c == '\r\n'){
   seen = 0;
   column = 0;
   row = row + 1;
  }
}
```